# Why is result undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why is `result` `undefined`?

My code

```js
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
var result = document.querySelector('.result');
var a;

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    a = this.dataset.number;
  });
}
result.innerHTML = a;
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="r" data-number="2" value="Radio 1">Radio 1
<input type="radio" name="r" data-number="4" value="Radio 2">Radio 2
<input type="radio" name="r" data-number="8" value="Radio 3">Radio 3

<div class="result">Result</div>
```

Javascript

```
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
var result = document.querySelector('.result');
var a;

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    a = this.dataset.number;
  });
}
result.innerHTML = a;
```

I will be glad to any help

Comment: Assigning the value of the variable "a" should be where "a" is updated, inside the change callback function.

Comment: @Jeremy Close match, but OP probably *[needs clarification]* doesn't want to wait until something changed.

Comment: var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
var result = document.querySelector('.result');
var a;

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
  radios[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    a = this.dataset.number;
    result.innerHTML = a;
  });
}
Hope it will help

Comment: @NikxFabrizio No answer in comment. If it's a dupe, it is. If you think it's not a dupe, work to reopen it.

Comment: result.innerHTML = this.dataset.number; so works. But how is this value used in another expression?

Comment: @user202729 we're not in an examination room, if we can help someone with accurate answer and save the person some time/effort then it's worth doing.
stackoverflow is a place to provide answers to those who needs them.

Comment: @NikxFabrizio {this assumes the question is a real duplicate. not this case} The OP can check the duplicate target and find better answers. If you have a good answer, you should post there, as it can help both OP and future visitors, not here.

Comment: example https://jsfiddle.net/qrL8dxbs/ - why at the first choice - the necessary value is not displayed?